# Angular4 resize directive in bootstrap not aligning correctly

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Angular4 but am trying to use my knowledge from AngularJs to create a project.
I have created a directive that resizes an element based on a decimal percent * the width of the element.
So, if I have 6 items like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="answers row">
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="answer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" [bzResize]="resizeMultipler">
                        <i class="icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect them to line up correctly, as the link is the one with the resize directive applied. The link has CSS to make it a block element.
The resize directive looks like this:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[bzResize]'
})
export class ResizeDirective {
  @Input() bzResize: number;

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _element: ElementRef) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.resize(this.bzResize));
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(e)   {
    setTimeout(() => this.resize(this.bzResize), 500);
  };

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////

  private resize(multiplier) {
    var element = this._element.nativeElement;
    var width = element.clientWidth; 
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(element, 'height', width * multiplier + 'px');
  };
}
```

The issue I get doesn't always happen, only in some cases, but it is annoying.
Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

As you can see, there is an element out of line. In AngularJs you had to add a `$timeout` to fix issues like this, so that the code was applied after the DOM had finished loading. I have that in the `ngAfterViewInit` method, but it still occurs.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: is there a way you can replicate it so we can play around with the code?

Comment: I can try, will have to do it on Monday :D

Comment: No worries, by that time, I will try as well.